# How to get many matched patterns from multiple patterns match in perl

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

Is there a way to get multi-matched-patterns from "many '|' regex" matching.

Here is my code,

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
@matches = qw(google intel hp qualcomm app);

$keyword = join('|', @matches);

$string = "hello google app";

@founded = ($string =~ /($keyword)/);

print "Founded keyword is:" . join(" ", @founded);
```

I hope to get 'google and app', because this keywords are both matched in strings. But How sad, just get 'google'

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a [`/g` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) to your match:

```
@found = ($string =~ /($keyword)/g);
```

You'll get all the matches that way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the intersection of two lists:

```
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

my @matches = qw(google intel hp qualcomm app);
my @find = qw(hello google app);

my @result = intersect(@matches, @find);
print "Founded keyword(s): ", join(" ", @result) . "\n";
```

This solution uses the [Array::Utils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Array%3a%3aUtils) module